# Book where son flies to different planets for shipping company and spy mechanic

Tags: story-identification, books

I read something last year and can't remember what it was. The main character was a "trust fund type" who flew to different planets for his father's shipping company. But he would go to places that needed help smuggle in the cargo they needed. His mother was an assassin. I think his father too. His whole crew were the same kind of people. A woman joined as a mechanic but she was there to spy on him for someone ( I think his brother?) Who wanted to capture and kill him. I think I remember him having another crew member that was an android his father made when he was a kid. I think I remember them describing the android as blue with white hair. If anyone can help me remember that'd be great.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This is a good question, but you might still be able to improve it; check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they help you recall anything else.

Comment: One quick question about the format -- did you read this as a Kindle e-book, or as a paperback novel, or what? The answer might help narrow things down.

Answer (score 1):

A very weak match would be *[Angel Station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angel_Station_(novel))* by Walter Jon Williams.

- Brother and sister operating the ship inherited from their dad.
- Financial issues.
- Another ship, infiltration, spying, sabotage.

Comment: The first contact part of AS would be the most notable feature someone would remember.